# Login failed for user 'sa'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have server pc with 2012 server and sql 2012 installed when I am connecting to my other server from this pc then I got this error

```
 Login failed for user 'sa'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)
```

[image]

That server is accessible from any other pc 
If I changed my local server user ‘sa’ password from that server user ‘sa’ password then it is connecting
I am unable to connect any other sql from this server pc

After 4-5 days r&d i found that problem is from internet provider side. using other net i am able to connect.

Comment: Check sqlsever log for more info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Serg as i explain only from this server pc i am not able to connect any sql

Comment: The log of the sqlserver you attempt to connect to  should list the detailes of what is happenning.

Comment: @Serg i dont understand if both server user 'sa' password is same then it was connecting

Comment: Information you currently provided is not sufficient to understand why connection is rejected.

Comment: As the others have said, connect the the instance from a host you can and check the error logs. That will give you the real reason (I suspect incorrect password).

Comment: No one understands why it's not connecting. That is why you should follow the advice and check the SQL Server Logs.

Comment: Error 18456 means that entered invalid credentials when logging into SQL Server. So, perhaps password as other members mentioned

Comment: *I am unable to connect any other sql from this server pc* - different keyboard layout? :) Have you tried to store password in a plain text and then copy-paste to a SSMS

Comment: @AlexanderVolok i have tried copy paste with plain text file but it not work. if i change 'sa' password as same then it will connect.

Answer (score 5):

I share for the community

1. Enable status login for the current user (for instance sa)
2. change server properties to sql authorization

follow the link scrren shots for details
https://www.yazilimkodlama.com/sql-server-2/sql-server-18456-hatasi-cozumu-login-failed-for-user-sa/